# Two way binding with custom signal with Reactive Cocoa not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have custom UITextField which has `NSDecimalNumber` value. I want to bind it two way to my model's `price` keypath.

Problem is that price is field is brutto price and is dependent on my custom build signal (sum of price, tax, discount etc signal)

So I tried to create `RACChannelTerminal`'s like in code below but I am still getting infinite loop of updates. TextField is updating price, and price is updating TextField.

Anyone can give me a hint how to make this Two-Way data binding work?

```
// Connecting two way PRICE
RACChannel *channelForProductPrice = [[RACChannel alloc] init];
[channelForProductPrice.followingTerminal subscribeNext:^(NSDecimalNumber *newValue) {
    self.product.price = [Price priceWithDecimalNumber:newValue];
}];
[[[[self.product rac_signalForPrice] takeUntil:[channelForProductPrice.followingTerminal
                                                ignoreValues]] map:^NSDecimalNumber *(Price *nettoPrice) {
    return [self.product calculatePriceWithTax:YES withDiscount:NO unit:YES rounded:YES].value;
}] subscribe:channelForProductPrice.followingTerminal];


RACChannel *channelForBruttoTextField = [[RACChannel alloc] init];
[channelForBruttoTextField.followingTerminal subscribeNext:^(NSDecimalNumber *value) {
    self.bruttoPriceTextField.value = value;
}];
[[[[self.bruttoPriceTextField rac_signalForValueChange] takeUntil:[channelForBruttoTextField.followingTerminal ignoreValues]] map:^id(id value) {
    NSDecimalNumber *newPrice = [value decimalNumberByDividingBy:self.product.tax.taxRatePlusOneAsPercentage];
    return newPrice;
}] subscribe:channelForBruttoTextField.followingTerminal];


[channelForProductPrice.leadingTerminal subscribe:channelForBruttoTextField.leadingTerminal];
[channelForBruttoTextField.leadingTerminal subscribe:channelForProductPrice.leadingTerminal];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're piping *followingTerminal -(map)-> price -> followingTerminal*, and there's nothing there to break that cycle. I don't think that is really the configuration you mean.

You might be better off setting up some `RACSignal`s rather than `RACChannel`s, breaking cycles with `distinctUntilChanged` or similar, and with `skip:` as appropriate to stop bad values flowing when you hook things up. At the moment, the exact flow of information through this isn't clear to me.

Comment: Yes, I finally used `distinctUntilChanged`. I read that they want to remove RACChannel from ReactiveCocoa 3.0 because its to hard to detect cycles.